# Storing base abstract class attributes in subclass db-table

Tags: c#, database, class, inheritance, abstract

I'm having some issues with storing attributes from my abstract class, the constructor seems to work just fine. However I'm not able to store the base attributes in my subclass database table.

```
public abstract class Vehicle : IComparable< Vehicle >, IComparable {
    public Int16 VehicleID;
    public DateTime ProductionDate;

    public Vehicle(Int16 _ Vehicle ID,DateTime _ProductionDate)
    {
        this.AccidentID = _ AccidentID;
        this.ProductionDate = _ProductionDate;
    }

    int IComparable.CompareTo(object other) {
        return CompareTo((Vehicle)other);
    }
    public int CompareTo(Vehicle other){
        return this.ProductionDate.CompareTo(other.ProductionDate);
    }

    public Vehicle()
    {}
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car ()
    {
    }

    public Car (Int16 _VehicleID,DateTime _ProductionDate, Int16 _CarAttribute1, Int16 _CarAttribute2):base(_Vehicle ID,_ProductionDate)
    {
        this.AccidentID = _ AccidentID;
        this.ProductionDate = _ProductionDate;
        this.CarAttribute1 = _CarAttribute1
        this.CarAttribute2 = _CarAttribute2

    }

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("Attribute1")]
    public Int16 CarAttribute1{ get; set;}
    [Column("Attribute2")]
    public Int16 CarAttribute2{ get; set;}
}
```

I'm quite new to C# so some guidance is appreciated :) What have I missed?

Comment: 1. Which framework do you use to work with DB? 2. What issues do you have with your code? Exception, wrong or NULL data in DB?

Comment: Hi, I'm using mono and the Xamarin IDE where I use a component called SQLite.net async (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/) The base class attributes are null in my database columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base class you should use properties instead of fields, so adjust your base class like this:

```
public abstract class Vehicle : IComparable<Vehicle>, IComparable {

public Int16 AccidentID { get; set; }
public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set;}

public Vehicle(Int16 _ Vehicle ID,DateTime _ProductionDate)
{
    this.AccidentID = _ AccidentID;
    this.ProductionDate = _ProductionDate;
}

int IComparable.CompareTo(object other) {
    return CompareTo((Vehicle)other);
}
public int CompareTo(Vehicle other){
    return this.ProductionDate.CompareTo(other.ProductionDate);
}

public Vehicle()
{}
```

}

so I changed:

```
public Int16 VehicleID;
public DateTime ProductionDate;
```

to:

```
public Int16 AccidentID { get; set; }
public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set;}
```

**BTW:** You have VehicleID field in base class, but in constructor you set value to AccidentID instead of VehicleID. I think it is just a typo in description, right? So I used **AccidentID** as property name, so please check if it is correct.